# How to freeze system clock for a wine application?

Tags: linux, wine, clock

I have a windows program, that works only to a particular date. It's a legacy application and I can't change the source code.

Is there any way to set a specific date in the system clock for the wine instance where I run it, so that the time in this instance is always day X?